# C# Json formatting from Class

Tags: c#, json

I have a C# class

```
public class occ
{
    public datetime from    { get; set; }
    public datetime to      { get; set; }
    public string   Ktype   { get; set; }
    public flag     bool    { get; set; }
}
```

that I fill from an EF6.0 function coming from a stored procedure

I was asked to create for each record of that class a Json of this format

```
{
"Ktype": [
    {
        "from"
        "to"
        "flag"
    }
]
```

}

I have a little experience with Json. Some folks here have helped me to catch up.

Until now I knew that the "outer" attribute (I do not know how to call it...sorry) came from the class name.

In this example the **Ktype** is a part of the class.

How can I Json-serialize this class and have Ktype as an outer Json attrib?

I want something like this:

```
 {
        "TRC": [{"from":"2016-02-09","to":"2016-02-16","flag":true}]
 }

{
        "TRX": [{"from":"2016-02-12","to":"2016-02-18","flag":false}]
}
```

Comment: why has `ktype` become an array (Its just a string in the class)? How do you map between the class and the required json?

Comment: What serializer do you use?

Comment: @James ISO 8601 - not a problem. I can handle that.

Comment: @jamiec We have that set of data (the class set) for providing information. One customer asked the above transformation in his json result.

Comment: You should create types that match the json format and either only use those or map to those, then create json from those types, this would make it easier to handle the one property becoming an array.

Comment: I have added a Json exampe output

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, maybe this will help you:

```
public class occ
{
    public List<Ktype> ktype { get; set;}

    public occ()
    {
        this.ktype = new List<Ktype>();
    }
}

public class Ktype
{
    public datetime from    { get; set; }
    public datetime to      { get; set; }
    public flag     bool    { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luca but I think that in your example ktype data is nowhere to be found. ktype is a string and its data should exist in the json.

Answer (score 1):

The following when populated and serialized yields the `json` below:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Ktype> Ktype { get; set; } = new List<Ktype>();
}
public class Ktype
{
    public DateTime from { get; set; }
    public DateTime to { get; set; }
    public bool flag { get; set; }
}
```

json:

```
{
    "Ktype": [{
        "from": "2016-01-28T14:43:10.3103658+00:00",
        "to": "2016-01-28T14:43:10.3103658+00:00",
        "flag": true
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SerializeObject` from newtonsoft lib:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new occ(), Formatting.Indented);
```

For more information [check this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Create a KTypeDto like this

```
public class KTypeDto
{
    public List<KType> KTypes { get; set;}
}

public class KType
{
    public Datetime From { get; set; }
    public Datetime To { get; set; }
    public Flag Bool { get; set; }
}
```